# I am not able to output to file using pjscrape

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am trying to scrape the entire page and save it into a JSON file using [PJScrape](https://github.com/nrabinowitz/pjscrape)
The following code runs and I can see the entire DOM in standard output, but I don't see the file scrape_output.json in the current directory

```
pjs.addSuite({
    // single URL or array
    url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_towns_in_Vermont',
    // single function or array, evaluated in the client
    scraper: function() {
        return $(document).text();
    },

    // options: 'json' or 'csv'
    format: 'json',
    // options: 'stdout' or 'file' (set in config.outFile)
    writer: 'file',
    outFile: 'scrape_output.json'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Logging is configured in pjs.config

```
pjs.addSuite({
    // single URL or array
    url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_towns_in_Vermont',
    // single function or array, evaluated in the client
    scraper: function() {
        return $(document).text();
    }
});

pjs.config({
    // options: 'stdout', 'file' (set in config.logFile) or 'none'
    log: 'stdout',
    // options: 'json' or 'csv'
    format: 'json',
    // options: 'stdout' or 'file' (set in config.outFile)
    writer: 'file',
    outFile: 'scrape_output.json'
});
```